# AngularJS navigation with key events

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create navigation via key events between entries. Left and right keys to move towards either end. It works similarly to this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjTxB/) i modified from someone although in the actual one each entry would have its own links to the previous and next one.

```
angular.element($document).bind("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.which === 37) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $location.path("/Book/Moby");
    });
  } else if (event.which === 39) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $location.path("/Book/Gatsby");
    });
  }
});
```

It seems to work fine in the JsFiddle but if you look at the console and see the amount of events fired from left and right keyups it will seriously slow down navigation. Each one of those events will run $location.path.

Any advice on how to listen to an event only once or flush old events would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `unbind` it before binding it.

```
angular.element($document).unbind('keyup');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      First of all you have to check whether it is hide from bottom side or upper side.
```

Let's suppose element is li,which used to be most common dom .

```
<ul>
<li></li> 
<li></li>
<li></li> 
<li></li>
<ul>
```

then every li height is relative postion of ul .If there are 1000 elements then if you want find out the position of 900th element then you can find out with offset() but when you apply animate and make them visible you will got stuck that scroll is not moving element which is hidden it should be more .

```
use some Mathematics Height*nth:child will always give you a right position
```

providing fiddle expamle so that basic concept will get clear
http://jsfiddle.net/MGwVM/108/